# Display last updated row in overview page - Excel

Tags: excel, list, vba, rows, auto-update

I have a shared workbook in excel with several sheets and a main sheet called overview.

e.g. Overview - Sheet1 - Sheet2 - Sheet 3

In sheet 1/2/3 me or others update the rows with some data.

It is hard to keep track of the last entries in the workbook (because i would need to search in all the sheets), so i would like to create a "top 10" dynamic list in my overview page that would update automatically with the last 10 updated rows within the workbook.

Can somebody help me on this?

Here's an example: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details, at least row dimensions on every sheet, e.g. columns A:E or similarly. And... [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Hi, the dimensions would be for the whole page, to capture any new rows updated with info.

A1:R1 - Columns
A1:A10000 - Rows

Please see my link above for clarification.

I haven't tried much because im not sure how to do this..not sure if excel can do this..

thanks

Comment: Let's wait for the promised solution) I'm pretty sure it will be based on VBA `SheetChange` event.

Comment: @PeterL. - you were right. I hope it was worth the wait... although I used `Worksheet_Change` if you want to get picky about it. :-)

Comment: @Floris Great job man. Hope you'll get your deserved Accept

Comment: @PeterL. - thanks. Maybe it will even get some upvotes? I had been meaning to create something like this for a while - I think it's got quite broad applicability with minimal edits.

Comment: @Floris buddy you got at least mine - I'd use that for "history tracking" of our test cases kept in excel. Brilliant! BTW have some ideas how to improve it even more: it would be nice to have a clickable link for every record in summary source column pointed to the changed row. Well, will try to adopt it)))

Comment: Thanks @PeterL I agree the link would be a nice touch, especially of you have really large sheets. If you use the "real" address of a row as reference (rather than the row number) for the `source` column, it might even be robust to rows being deleted / inserted. Let me know how it works out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be this:

Add an event handler at the workbook level to capture cells being changed; in the handler, do these things:

- turn off event handling (you are going to change the worksheet and don't want to go into an infinite loop)!
- turn off screen updating
- insert a row on the front sheet, in row 1
- enter a copy of the changed row there
- add the user who changed it, and the date/time, in an additional column (if you would like)
- return to the original selection
- turn on screen updating
- turn on event handling

Here are the step-by-step instructions (example file can be downloaded from http://www.floris.us/SO/download/XLexample.xlsm) - assuming Excel 2010 on PC. Other versions will have mostly small differences...

1. Make sure your file is saved as `.xlsm` format - this tells Excel there are macros
2. Create a backup of the file before adding all this stuff - in case you mess something up!
3. Close all other files (for now) - see earlier comment
4. Make sure your file has four worksheets: "summary", "widgets", "things", and "stuff" (or whatever names you find helpful - I will refer to them by these names, rather than "Sheet1" etc.)
5. Right-click on the tab of "widgets", and select "View code"
6. paste the following code into the "code" window for the worksheet:

.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByBal Target as Range)
  On Error GoTo procErr
  process_change Target
  Exit Sub

procErr:
  MsgBox "Got an error: " & Err.Description
  Err.Clear
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`
```

1. Repeat the above steps for each of the "data" worksheets: "things", and "stuff" (but NOT for "summary")
2. While the Visual Basic Editor is open (that's where you did all that pasting), insert a new code module in the workbook, using Insert->Module
3. Paste the following code in the module you created:

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub process_change(ByVal Target As Range)
' when a cell is changed on one of the worksheets, this function is called
' it copies the most recently changed row
' and inserts it on the second line of the "summary" worksheet
' right below the headers
' if the headers include "changed by" and/or "last changed" (exactly)
' then that column will be updated with the (windows) user name and date, respectively
' similarly, if a column named "source" exists, it will contain the address of the row
' (sheet name / row number). In that case, if there was an earlier occurrence of the same row
' (multiple edits), the earlier occurence is removed
' you may use this code as is - but there is no warranty as to its useability

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim srcAddress As String
Dim oldSelection As Range

' don't update screen during processing - prevent "flickering"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' set to True when debugging

' don't accept events until we're done
Application.EnableEvents = False

' store old selection
Set oldSelection = Selection

Dim ri As Integer           ' index of changed row
Dim rowAddress As String
ri = Target.Row
rowAddress = ri & ":" & ri  ' address of changed row

if ri = 1 Then
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub                  ' don't record changes to the headers
End If

Range(rowAddress).Select
Selection.Copy              ' copy changed row

Set s1 = ActiveSheet        ' know where we will go back to
srcAddress = s1.Name & ":row" & ri ' full address to be used later

Set s2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("summary")

s2.Range("2:2").Insert      ' add a row at the top of the list
s2.Select                   ' activate sheet where we want to paste
Range("A2").Select          ' leftmost cell of column
ActiveSheet.Paste           ' paste the entire changed row

' optionally, we can add "source", "last changed" and "changed by"
' we do this if appropriately named columns exist
' slightly clumsy code to catch errors...
Dim lcCol
If Not IsError(Application.Match("last changed", Range("1:1"), 0)) Then
  lcCol = Application.Match("last changed", Range("1:1"), 0)
  Range("A2").Offset(0, lcCol - 1).Value = Date
End If

Dim cbCol
If Not IsError(Application.Match("changed by", Range("1:1"), 0)) Then
  cbCol = Application.Match("changed by", Range("1:1"), 0)
  Range("A2").Offset(0, cbCol - 1).Value = UserName
End If

Dim srcCol
If Not IsError(Application.Match("source", Range("1:1"), 0)) Then
  srcCol = Application.Match("source", Range("1:1"), 0)
  ' find earlier entry regarding this row...
  Columns("A:A").Offset(0, srcCol - 1).Select
  Dim sf As Range
  Set sf = Selection.Find(What:=srcAddress, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  If Not sf Is Nothing Then
  ri = sf.Row
  rowAddress = ri & ":" & ri  ' address of changed row
  Range(rowAddress).Select
  Selection.Delete
  End If
  Range("A2").Offset(0, srcCol - 1).Value = srcAddress
End If

s1.Activate                     ' go back to original worksheet
Application.CutCopyMode = False ' get rid of the "marching ants"
oldSelection.Select             ' select the previous selection "like nothing happened"

' and turn on screenupdating and events...
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub eventsOn()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Function UserName()
' note - this function only works on PC
  UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```

With all that done, you can now put headers in your sheets - use the same column headers in all four sheets. In the first (summary) sheet, you can optionally add three more headers: these should not be the same as other headers you used, and be called (exactly - no extra spaces, capitalization, ...): `source`, `last changed`, `changed by`.

If these last three column headings are not there, the behavior will be as follows:

Every time you make a change to one of the three worksheets, the row in which the change was made will be copied into the first row of the summary sheet, below the headers. Everything else will move down one row.

If you add the "source" column, two things will happen: the source (sheet name : row number) will be added in that column, and any previous entries for that same source (same row) will be deleted. Thus you will only see "the most recent change" for a given row.

If you add "changed by", you will get the name of the user who made the last change; the "last changed" header will have the date of the last change.

Let me know if you can figure it out from here - use the example spreadsheet which I linked above to guide you if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi,

not very familiar with VBA, is it possible to use some formulas in excel to do this? 

What im looking for is this:  http://s9.postimage.org/mjkh64h4v/pic.png .

Thanks

Comment: Hang in there... I have created a "complete solution" for you. Can't upload it right now - but you're going to love it. Will be able to give it in about two hours. Will be worth the wait, I promise.

Comment: Just looked at the format of the spreadsheet you used. It's pretty trivial to change the column headers to get what you were asking for... I did just realize that if you start editing headers, these changes will show up as an "edit to row 1". I will modify the code to trap that...

Comment: Thanks Floris, i will give that a go.

The link you gave me is asking me for login details, i cannot download the file without those.

Comment: thanks Floris, that worked ! Just one more question, what do i need to do if i want to cover the data in more columns?
At the moment i have issue, description, date . can i add more and get them monitored as well?

Comment: Just add columns to all sheets, in the same order, and it will work. Make sure the "changed by" etc columns are to the right of the others or they risk getting overwritten.

Comment: Oh - and "that worked" is best said by "accepting" the answer... Click the check mark next to it.

Comment: Hi Floris,

one more question.. this script works perfectly and is very good, i am trying to make another board with just Open items. My column L has Open or Closed in the cell, i would need to run this script and instead of pasting all of the rows in the summary tab, it would paste only the rows that contains the word "Open" in the L tab on another sheet "SummaryOpen". Can you help me with that? Thank you

Comment: @Slider105 - there are several solutions. The easiest of these doesn't require VBA. You could autofilter on column L in the summary sheet (ribbon: Data->filter, and little pull down menus appear in the top row); by turning this filter on and off you can see the "open" items. Or you can duplicate some of the code above (from `Set s2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("summary")` to just before `s1.activate`, and do the same thing but with your other sheet. You would have to add a condition (`if` statement) to skip the second sheet if the L column does not contain "Open". Let me know if you're still stuck.

Comment: Can you check this? Im probably miles away...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jubdgpyedeky3rf/excelcode.txt

Comment: Yeah - you are miles away. Will have to be "for after hours". I hope you're not in a rush.

Comment: no rush. I will keep trying to see if i can get anywhere. Thanks

Comment: Floris, no luck so far, ended up messing the code somewhat... any chance you can check this if its not trouble?

Comment: I have uploaded a new file in the same location as before: http://www.floris.us/SO/download/XLexample.xlsm . This should address all the questions you had. It even addresses the situation where rows are added or deleted, and "updates" the "open" sheet even when an issue is no longer open (it finds the old open issue, and removes it). You owe me something. Not sure what, yet... :-)

Comment: i Agree ! That is sweet !! Put it working now and everything is awesome. Not to push it heh if i need to do one for just closed items and just for pending items, it would be just to duplicate the code you inserted last and change the variables s3 to s4 right?Thanks man, this is really great help!! :)

btw, post this reply in this link so i can give you points for this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737476/clone-rows-from-one-sheet-to-the-other-containing-a-value

Comment: And as for your other question - try it, and see if it works. It's how you learn... :-)

Comment: There - I knew you would. Thanks for letting me know!