# Clone Rows from one sheet to the other containing a value

Tags: vba, excel, clone

I have a "sheet1" containing several headings and i'm looking to see if there is a formula i can ran that will scan, filter only the rows whereas the Column G has the status as "open".

see example: http://s18.postimage.org/897u71lnt/excel2.png

I want all of the "Open" items to be copied on the "sheet2" automatically. Everytime that sheet1 is updated with a new issue and has Open on the G column , sheet 2 will get this values.

Is it possible to do this without VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try filtering the "Open" values? The only need is to reapply filter as new items appear.

Comment: tried that.. the problem is when filtering i get a mix of the rows, they are not in sequence anymore as 1..2..3 etc. 
http://s11.postimage.org/nmmyfcx77/excel3.png 

I have another formula like a "top 20" board on sheet3 and i want to fill that board with the first 20 open issues. It does not work when the rows change ..

Comment: Assuming the input the solution is VBA-only... and it's not a 2-lines code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PeterL pointed out, it's not "two lines of code". However, there is a solution...
I have posted a complete Excel workbook with macros at [this link](http://www.floris.us/SO/download/XLexample.xlsm) . It does not only what you are asking in this question, but addresses some of the questions you asked in previous comments, and has additional functionality you didn't even know to ask for (like "if a previously 'open' issue now becomes 'closed', it needs to be removed from the list of 'open' issues).